# sbt-assembly spark not working but sbt run does

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, sbt, sbt-assembly

I'm developing a Spark app that needs to be a single fat-jar, it's meant to be run in local mode, no cluster or Hive instance installed, just the jar.

If I run the code using `sbt run` it works as expected, yet, the fat-jar made with `sbt assembly` returns an Exception of Hive not able to instantiate `HiveMetaStoreClient`.

**To reproduce**:

*main.scala*

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Main extends App {
  var spark =
    SparkSession.builder
      .appName("logiQ")
      .config("spark.master", "local[2]")
      .enableHiveSupport
      .getOrCreate

  System.setSecurityManager(null)

  spark.sql("create database test")
  spark.sql("show databases").show
}
```

*build.sbt*

```scala
name := "test"

scalaVersion := "2.12.11"
val sparkVersion = "2.4.6"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" %  sparkVersion

assemblyJarName in assembly := s"${name.value}.jar"

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
    case PathList("META-INF", "MANIFEST.MF") => MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
    case "plugin.xml" => MergeStrategy.last
    case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

How is that possible, isn't a fat-jar just a jar containing all dependencies, why does `sbt run` works? What hidden magic am I missing here?

Comment: Could you provide more of the stack trace?

Comment: A **Spark** program that is not meant to be run in an **Spark** _cluster_ probably does not need to use **Spark** at all.

Comment: BTW I would suggest you make these dependencies provided. When you run spark-submit they will already be there.

Comment: I'm using spark because I cannot find or think of a simple enough solution of running spark-sql queries without it, if you know something that can do that, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: Because we need table support, and without spark complains that it cannot create tables.